# How to change the download location of games through Origin?

Tags: origin

I want to change the download location of games, but on the 'Installs & Saves' tab it won't let me choose my D:\ partition, where I normally download my games. Even at the install of Origin I can't select that drive.
How can I change that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a game that is already installed and you want to move or something that is not downloaded yet?  If it's already installed, you can try [moving it](https://i2.wp.com/crinrict.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Move.jpg).

Comment: Yours is weird looking... my file explorer at least shows me my drives on the left hand side of the File Explorer window.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to change, the way it looks so it shows me the drives on the left but idk how to do that

Comment: Are you able to just type in "D:\"?

Comment: Nope, it searches only on C.

Comment: There is something very wrong here. Try restarting Windows (or killing explorer.exe and restarting it from the task manager)

Comment: It just looks like the navigation pane is missing - see my answer to add it back in. You should be able to select another disk/folder then.

Comment: Long shot, but, if this is not your personal computer, then there might be a small chance that a group policy been set to limit usable drives. See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/231289/using-group-policy-objects-to-hide-specified-drives) for details

Comment: @DrFish I don't think that's a long shot, it seems like a very reasonable option. Or Origin doesn't have the proper authority to access the drive. Or the drive is corrupted.

Comment: @Smock If entering the drive letter doesn't help, I doubt being able to select it in the navigation pane will..

Comment: @Joachim Hmm yes, entering the `d:` should do the trick, but if as @DrFish says there's something preventing him entering things in there, then more luck might be had selecting the drive with the mouse (That's the way I've seen a group policy blocking entering in directories work elsewhere). In any case, I wonder if OP could show the navigation pane just so we can see what's in there - it might give us a clue. (Or a screenshot of 'This PC' view or diskmgmt.msc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the navigation pane back:

[image: Navigation Pane]

Click on `Organise -> Layout -> Navigation Pane`

You should get back all your drives/etc then.

**If that doesn't help - could you follow these instructions and post a screenshot of what does appear in the navigation pane.**

Comment: I don't think changing drive visibility in Windows will help at all. That's a GUI problem, but the OP's problem is that the drive seems non-existent.